# C# Generics - can this be done better?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to get my head around Generics and am refactoring an existing class. I would appreciate feedback on whether it could be done better.

I have a number of ViewModels which implement similar behaviour and could be derived from a common class. An example would be:

```
public class SelectSupplierViewModel : SelectViewModel<SupplierAModel>
```

SupplierAModel is an ISelectModel.

The following class enables a view which displays a menu of items to work with multiple types of data

```
public class SelectViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase where T : ISelectModel
{
  public Action<SelectViewModel<T>> OnItemSelected;

  public IEnumerable<T> Selections { get; set; }  

  public T SelectedItem
  {
      get { return null; }
      set {
          RaisePropertyChanged();
          OnItemSelected?.Invoke(this);
      }
  }

  .
  .
  .
```

OnItemSelected is hooked up to a handler in a separate class.  It is executed on the earlier 'Invoke':

```
private void OnSupplierSelected(SelectViewModel<SelectAModel> viewModel)
{
    // When I inspect viewModel I can see that viewModel is a 
    // SelectSupplierViewModel, and I need to access properties on 
    // this.

    // Is it possible to do so without casting viewModel to    
    // SelectSupplierViewModel?
}
```

It was not possible to have a method accepting a SelectSupplierViewModel as the SelectViewModel class is expecting SelectViewModel.

Thankyou!

Comment: If `OnSupplierSelected()` requires a `SelectSupplierViewModel` then make the parameter that more derived type. Otherwise you're violating the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I'd like to accept a parameter of SelectSupplierViewModel but I can't understand how to do so as the Action is less specific.

Comment: This belongs in code review. There is no bug or problem to solve here. You will get much better feedback in a site meant precisely for code reviews.

Comment: @InBetween - no, this does not belong on review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the deriving type to the type parameters of `SelectViewModel<>` like so:

```
public class SelectViewModel<TModel, TViewModel> : ViewModelBase 
    where TModel : ISelectModel, TViewModel: SelectViewModel<TModel, TViewModel>
{
```

Note that you have to add a generic type constraint for `TViewModel` so you can cast `this` to `TViewModel` when invoking the event handler.

Use `TViewModel` for your event declaration:

```
public Action<TViewModel> OnItemSelected;
```

...and for its invocation:

```
OnItemSelected?.Invoke((TViewModel)this);
```

Deriving from the new base class is similar -- just add the type you are about to declare to the type parameter list:

```
public class SelectSupplierViewModel 
    : SelectViewModel<SupplierAModel, SelectSupplierViewModel>
{
```

Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8gHBwj